# Git Personal Access Token caching

Tags: github, git-credential-manager

Error message showing when I use `git push`:

```bash
"C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\gh.exe auth git-credential get: 
C:ProgramDataMiniconda3Scriptsgh.exe: command not found"
```

The `git push` task is completed successfully, but this error message is showing annoyingly.
I already cached my PAT with GitHub CLI successfully.
My only problem is that above error message.

[image: Error]

Help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `git config credential.helper` (or `git config --global credential.helper`)

If it includes a path with `\` in it, do a `git config (--global) --edit`, and escape backslashes: each `\` becomes a `\\`.

Comment: It seems like nothing changes..

Comment: @SuwethanM What is the ouput of `git config --global credential.helper`?

Comment: It shows manager-core only.

Comment: @SuwethanM Can you check the output of git config --global -l? If you see a path starting with `C;\ Program Data\...`, without "" around it, add "".